# nodejs express template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to build a very simple mvc in node js and express js.
So far i've managed to show the right html according to the route taken "site/component/view/layout/bla.html"

Now i'm at the part where i have to take the data and put it in the website.
I know there are already template engines but I choose to make my own, simple, template engine.
So, i took the apropiate html, and parsed it to get the parts where i should replace with the data.
I put some start and end custom tags to get the content with regex.
I end up with a STRING like this

```
"for(var i = 0; i< list.length; i++) {
console.log(list[i]);
}"
```

Well this is from the parsed HTML. In the backend the "list" array will be taken from the model.

My problem is how do i parse that string to do exactly that, or just to put data in the site. I have to put another custom command like "write list[i].name" and parse it in the backend ? How do i know there is a for loop with 3 arguments, or a while loop. And how do i "execute" it ?
Not to mention "if" statements.. is there any easy way ?

Comment: "I know there are already template engines but I choose to make my own, simple, template engine." It doesn't sound very simple to me. Is there a reason why you're trying to build your own templating engine? The simplest option by far would be to choose an existing one. Mustache, handlebars, hogan, jade, EJS, etc all already support the collection iteration feature you're trying to reinvent.

Comment: there is no real reason behind it.. i just like it that way.. i like to learn the "how it's made" rather than just use it... Plus it's good exercise to know this stuff.. just in case.. So, do you have any sugestions? I read that eval might work, but it;s not very safe

Comment: All of the above are open source. My suggestion would be to draw inspiration from reading the code and seeing how they solved your problem. And eval is evil.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is something quite big.

Nocturno has answered a good solution but it's the best answer we can give you about. And here, you will have a solution with no cache who'll take alot of time and ressources to execute.

You don't have any caching system here nor functions/helpers like `if()` or `foreach()`. I recommend you to have a look to [that website](https://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) who is great to find out a proper template engine.

*For example*, I'm using [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/), and this is how I pass variables from my back-work to view

```
templateEngines = ["Handlebars", "Jade", "Mustache", "EJS"];

res.render("index", {
    list : templateEngine
});
```

... and the view (/views/index.handlebars/)

```
<h1>List of template engines I've used in mah life :</h1>
<ul>
    {{#each list}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

And it'll give this HTML at access:

```
<h1>List of template engines I've used in mah life :</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Handlebars</li>
    <li>Jade</li>
    <li>Mustache</li>
    <li>EJS</li>
</ul>
```

I understand your desire to recreate the hot water but trust me, you'll get something disappointing at the end. Do it when you're sure to bring something better to the Node.JS community otherwise, spend more time on your REST tutorial. Friendly advice!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I wanted to know if there is a "eval" alternative or i'll just end up using regex . I'm simply trying to learn to do js stuff.. And i find this problem quite interesting and provocative.. So i'm gonna keep trying to find a way to parse loops :) . Please don't post any more of this "just use an existing template engine". Just post sugestions if u have.. i just want to learn how things works

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is load up your html into a string, and then replace parts of it with your data before sending it back to the client?

1. Get the html from your html file using node's [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module
2. Store that html as a string.
3. Replace parts of that string with your data using the string's [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function.
4. Send that string back to the client in the response object: [res.send(myHTML)](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send).

Comment: Yes, this is what i'm doing right now. I'm stuck at loops

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'stuck at loops'?

Comment: As i wrote : I have something like this 
"for(var i = 0; i< list.length; i++) {
console.log(list[i]);
}"
that i a string taken from the HTML. I want to parse that to do what it's supposed to do. And that is to console.log in the browser.. And further to have something like php's "echo" . To put stuff in the html